# How to refactor this Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, refactoring

I have two methods in a DB helper class that do basically the same thing for two different database entities, and I would like to refactor them to avoid duplicating code.

The first entity:

```
- (void) insertOrUpdateEntityA:(NSDictionary*)data {
    sqlite3_stmt *exists_stmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLEntityAExists, -1, &exists_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:exists_stmt data:data from:1];
        if (sqlite3_step(exists_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int count = sqlite3_column_int(exists_stmt, 1);
            sqlite3_stmt *update_stmt;
            if (count) { // Update
                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLEntityAUpdate, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                    int index = [RMStoreDB bindEntityA:update_stmt data:data from:1];
                    [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:data from:index];
                }
            } else { // Insert
                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLEntityAInsert, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                    int index = [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:data from:1];
                    [RMStoreDB bindEntityA:update_stmt data:data from:index];
                }           
            }
            sqlite3_step(update_stmt);
            sqlite3_finalize(update_stmt);
        }           
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(exists_stmt);
}
```

The second entity:

```
 - (void) insertOrUpdateEntityB:(NSDictionary*)data {
    sqlite3_stmt *exists_stmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLEntityBExists, -1, &exists_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:exists_stmt data:data from:1];
        if (sqlite3_step(exists_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int count = sqlite3_column_int(exists_stmt, 1);
            sqlite3_stmt *update_stmt;
            if (count) { // Update
                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLEntityBUpdate, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                    int index = [RMStoreDB bindEntityB:update_stmt data:data from:1];
                    [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:data from:index];
                }
            } else { // Insert
                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLEntityBInsert, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                    int index = [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:data from:1];
                    [RMStoreDB bindEntityB:update_stmt data:data from:index];
                }           
            }
            sqlite3_step(update_stmt);
            sqlite3_finalize(update_stmt);
        }           
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(exists_stmt);
}
```

The differences are the constants used for the SQL statements (`RMSQLEntityAExists`, `RMSQLEntityBExists`, etc.) and the method used to bind the data to the SQLite statement (`bindEntityA` and `bindEntityB`). The latter is what I'm finding particularly challenging to generalize.

How do I refactor these two methods? Should I?

Comment: Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: But then I wouldn't learn how to refactor this particular code. ;)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not use inheritance for this.  Inheritance is for sharing interface, not for sharing implementation.  You have two methods with very similar implementations, but different interfaces.

Second, consider one of the primary principles declared by the GoF: identify what changes and encapsulate it.  The easiest way to do this in this case would be to extract out some meaningful methods.  If nothing else this will make your code easier to read.  You should shoot for something like this (I'm using pseudo code, since I don't really know what your code is doing):

```
- (void)insertOrDeleteItem:(NSDictionary *)item {
    if ([self databaseAppearsToBeWorking]]) {
        row = [self findRowForItem:item];
        if (row) {
            [self updateRow:row withItem:item];
        } else {
            [self insertItem:item];
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have something that looks more like that then the commonalities will either present themselves more clearly, or you'll discover that the methods actually should remain distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass both entities off a common object with that method in the root object.

The differential can be modified using ivars that you set up in the subclass init methods and a call out to a mutated method

Like so...

```
@interface RootEntity : MyObject {

    NSString *statementmech1;
    NSString *statementmech2;
    NSString *statementmech3;
}

@interface Entity1 : RootEntity {

}

@interface Entity2 : RootEntity {

}
```

and

```
@implementation RootEntity

-(void)variantMethod
{
  //varies in subclasses
}

    - (void) insertOrUpdateItem:(NSDictionary*)item {
        sqlite3_stmt *exists_stmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, statementmech1 , -1, &exists_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:exists_stmt data:item from:1];
            if (sqlite3_step(exists_stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int count = sqlite3_column_int(exists_stmt, 1);
                sqlite3_stmt *update_stmt;
                if (count) { // Update
                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, statementmech2, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                        int index = [RMStoreDB bindItem:update_stmt data:item from:1];
                        [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:item from:index];
                    }
                } else { // Insert
                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, statementmech3, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                        [self variantMethod];
                    }           
                }
                sqlite3_step(update_stmt);
                sqlite3_finalize(update_stmt);
            }           
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(exists_stmt);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create an extra class that can't be instantiated? Since Objective-C doesn't have abstract classes, I find this might be misleading. Also, I edited the question to make it clearer that both methods are in a db helper class.

Comment: Who says Obj-C doesnt have abstract classes? Its a semantic division at best. If you really dont want this instantiated throw an exception in the root class init method.

Comment: Actually your edit removes the commonality in the method sig. Dont bother refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd change would be to add early returns; less-indented code is less intimidating:

```
- (void) insertOrUpdateItem:(NSDictionary*)item {
    sqlite3_stmt *exists_stmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLItemExists, -1, &exists_stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
        return;
    [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:exists_stmt data:item from:1];
    if (sqlite3_step(exists_stmt) != SQLITE_ROW)
        return;
    int count = sqlite3_column_int(exists_stmt, 1);
    sqlite3_stmt *update_stmt;
    if (count) { // Update
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLItemUpdate, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            int index = [RMStoreDB bindItem:update_stmt data:item from:1];
            [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:item from:index];
        }
    } else { // Insert
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, RMSQLItemInsert, -1, &update_stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            int index = [RMStoreDB bindPrimaryKey:update_stmt data:item from:1];
            [RMStoreDB bindItem:update_stmt data:item from:index];
        }           
    }
    sqlite3_step(update_stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(update_stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(exists_stmt);
}
```

Beyond that, it appears that the difference is that one is for items, and the other is for collections.  If you can put the item into a collection and then call insertOrUpdateCollection(), you're done.  I don't know objective C; in Java we would use Collections.singleton(), which, as the documentation says:

> Returns an immutable set containing
>   only the specified object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out early returns. However, in this case you're not finalizing the statements. Regarding "collections" and "items", the names were accidental, so I edited the question to make it more generic.